# retaining arrays

Tags: android

I'm creating quiz app of sorts for Android. The questions shall be posed in a random order, but every question should only appear once per run. For randomization, I'm creating a randomized array, with the index of each question in a separate class. This array is being passed on through an intent to the main class which is displaying the question.

Once the user has answered a question, I want to give him feedback. I do this by launching an activity telling him if he was right or wrong. After that, the question-activity is being restarted. The only problem now is that the randomized array is now gone.

How do I retain the array for later use? I really could use some help here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two `Activity` classes: question-asking (A), and right/wrong (B).

If you launch `startActivity` from "A" to get to "B", then don't restart the "A" once you're done with "B". Simply call `finish()` on "B".

This will ensure that you do not lose your data from the question `Activity`, and additionally will not start hundreds of `Activity` objects.

Comment: Don't forget to mark correct answers (with the little check box); it helps other people find the solution, and also encourages people to help you in the future!